# Como traduzir a "ErrorMessage" de um "Custom Attribute"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Criei um **Custom Attribute** que válida unicamente se uma propriedade **CPF** é um  CPF válido, porém ao Localizar a aplicação notei que meus **Custom Attribute** não estavam tendo suas mensagens localizadas pelo Framework ao contrário do `Data Attribute Required` que tem sua mensagem localizada corretamente:

Exemplo do uso dos atributos sendo que o Required é corretamente localizado

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF Requerido")]
[CPF(ErrorMessage = "CPF Inválido")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

Configuração da localização no arquivo Startup.cs

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
             return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        };
    });
```

Classe de validação customizada:

```
public class CPFAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        //Omitido por não fazer parte do context
    }
}
```

> **Versões:**
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1.1)
>
> Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.1)

Exemplo em inglês:

[image: Exemplo em inglês]

Exemplo em português:

[image: Exemplo em português]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa adicionar as configurações no construtor, ou na configuração do atributo, no construtor:

```
//base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "/*nome da chave*/" ou
base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(/*ResourceName*/);
```

ou no atributo:

```
[CPFAttribute(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(/*ResourceName*/).
```

Essa parte é somente a validação do servidor, precisa enviar a mensagem com `ValidationResult(ErrorMessage)` que é aquilo que você digitou na configuração `ErrorMessage`, ***exemplo***:

```
public class CPFAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public CPFAttribute()
    {
        base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "/*nome da chave*/"
        base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(/*ResourceName*/);
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (cpf for válido) //se for válido
        {
             return ValidationResult.Success;
        }   
        //se for inválido passe o valor da mensagem
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val","true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-cpf", 
                 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)) 
                 ? ErrorMessage 
                 : "CPF invalid");
    }
}
```

Também fui um pouco além e coloquei a implementação da parte do lado do cliente que agora precisa também criar a função no `jQuery.Validation` para funcionar também:

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('data-val-cpf',
        function (value, element, params) {                        
            cpf = value.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');  
            if(cpf == '') return false;                 
            if (cpf.length != 11 || 
                cpf == "00000000000" || 
                cpf == "11111111111" || 
                cpf == "22222222222" || 
                cpf == "33333333333" || 
                cpf == "44444444444" || 
                cpf == "55555555555" || 
                cpf == "66666666666" || 
                cpf == "77777777777" || 
                cpf == "88888888888" || 
                cpf == "99999999999")
                    return false;       
            // Valida 1o digito 
            add = 0;    
            for (i=0; i < 9; i ++)      
                add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (10 - i);  
                rev = 11 - (add % 11);  
                if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)     
                    rev = 0;    
                if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(9)))     
                    return false;       
            // Valida 2o digito 
            add = 0;    
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)       
                add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (11 - i);  
            rev = 11 - (add % 11);  
            if (rev == 10 || rev == 11) 
                rev = 0;    
            if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(10)))
                return false;       
            return true;
        }, function (params, element) {            
            var msgCompare = $(element).attr('data-val-cpf');
            if (!msgCompare) {
                msgCompare = 'CPF inválido';
            }
            return msgCompare;
        });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('data-val-cpf');
})(jQuery);
```

dessa forma você tem as duas validações com as mensagens que você configurou no código.

***Ref.*** [C# using resource file for validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482658/c-sharp-using-resource-file-for-validation-messages)

Comment: Então Virgilio, agradeço pela sua resposta mas acredito que o ponto que abordou não abarca a localização, hoje já é exibido a ErrorMessage do CPFAttribute, entretanto esta mensagem não é localizada assim como a do Required (que é uma annotation "padrão")

Comment: Se pode explicar melhor na sua pergunta @Ricardo passando exemplos?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo em português e inglês

Comment: Ele fica aparecendo só inglês? @Ricardo ???

Comment: Fica aparecendo somente em português "CPF inválido"

Comment: Eu não tenho como testar mas, quando chegar em casa eu faço @Ricardo dá uma olhada acho que isso resolve, porque, precisa informar para o atributo customizado o que ele precisa fazer ...